# mongoose how to update properties in document only if they exist in request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In order to update a document i usually do as such...

```
  Model.findById(id)
.then((doc) => {
  doc.fName = req.body.fName
    ? req.body.fName
    : doc.fName;
  doc.lName = req.body.lName 
  ? req.body.lName
  : doc.lName
  return doc.save();
})
.then((result) => res.send(" Succesfully updated ! New data: " + result))
.catch((err) => res.send(err));
```

..which checks if the field actually exists in the body request,otherwise it just passes the previous value.

Is there a way to just provide the fields in the request and let it do the check for itself so if a field does not exist,it will not delete it ? like so...

```
  Model.someMethod(id)
.then((doc) => {
  doc.fName = req.body.fName
  doc.lName = req.body.lName
  return doc.save();
})
.then((result) => res.send(" Succesfully updated ! New data: " + result))
.catch((err) => res.send(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using it in this way will only update the same field that you enter in the `req.body`.Other fields will be as it is. Which is in the fields `NOT_ALLOWED` variable will not be updated.

```
const NOT_ALLOWED = ['_id'] //Just the same field will update which are not in this variable
     Model.findById(id).then((docs) => {
        Object.keys(req.body).map((key) => {

            if (NOT_ALLOWED.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                docs[key] = req.body[key]
            }

        })
        return docs.save()
    })
        .then((result) => console.log("Updated Data", result))
        .catch((err) => res.send(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with one **update** query. First, you can construct the update config based on all the properties from the `req.body`. Then, just pass that update config to the **update** query. You can also pass `{ new: true }` as third config to **update** query, so the updated document will be returned.

```js
let update = {};
if (req.body.fName) update.fName = req.body.fName;
if (req.body.lName) update.lName = req.body.lName;

Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, { new: true })
  .then((result) => res.send(" Succesfully updated ! New data: " + result))
  .catch((err) => res.send(err));
```

Comment: Using this way only updated those fields which entered into in your update variable. every time I put in a new field in `req.body`, I have to change my code.this is look like a static way to update fields.

Comment: That's true, but you don't know what is in the `req.body`. Maybe there are some additional properties that should not change the database document.

Comment: That's Right but using my answer you update only those filed will match in your database and match in `req.body`.also use `NOT_ALLOWED` variable you set restrication to update the fields.

Comment: You answer will also work, but it makes 2 calls to the database. You can do all of that with one `update` query.

Comment: I know but `update` query gives limitations.we can update records with dynamic way that's why i use 2 calls to the database.